# SQL Right Outer Join return only cases with latest date

Tags: sql, outer-join

I have 2 tables, Referral and Hospital, and I am trying to do a join and see all referrals IDs that are related to a hospital unit.

When I run the following query, I get the data I need

```
    Select Referral.ReferralID, Hospital.Unit
    from Referral
    Join Hospital
    On Referral.HospitalUnit = Hospital.Unit
```

I also want to see the units that are not associated with a referral. So I do a right join and get my data

```
    Select Referral.ReferralID, Hospital.Unit
    from Referral
    Right Outer Join Hospital
    On Referral.HospitalUnit = Hospital.Unit
```

However, the units can have minor changes during the year, and this data gets recorded in the Hospital Unit table. I only want to return the row with the most updated date.

The reason for this is because the null referrals bring back the same unit multiple times. An example is below. I would then get multiple ICUs in my query when I only need 1

| Unit | Last Updated On |
| --- | --- |
| ICU | 10-9-2020 |
| CCU | 11-1-2020 |
| ICU | 11-1-2020 |

How would I be able to run a right outer join with just the latest Updated Date?

Comment: Why don't you just do a single query: `Hospital left join Referral on...`

Answer (score 0):

> I also want to see the units that are not associated with a referral.

`NOT EXISTS` seems the most natural approach:

```
select h.*
from hospital h
where not exists (select 1
                  from referral r
                  where r.HospitalUnit = h.Unit
                 );
```

If you want the most recent referral for each unit, use a subquery:

```
select h.*, r.*
from (select h.*,
             row_number() over (partition by r.HospitalUnit order by h.updated_on desc) as seqnum
      from hospital h
     ) h left join
     referral r
     on r.HospitalUnit = h.Unit 
where h.seqnum = 1;
```